# Handler instead of Timer?

Tags: java, android, timer, callback

Basically this is what I am doing, instead of using a `Timer` I am using a `Handler`:

```
Handler h = new Handler();    
Runnable r = new Runnable(){

public void run(){
 //do something and schedule it again
 h.postDelayed(r, 10000);
}

};
```

And I say `h.removeCallBacks(r);` when I want to stop it. Is it bad?

Comment: Down voters please do add a comment...

Comment: I think that's the proper way.

Comment: when you don't want to use it anymore,you can add one more thing after removing callbacks,h=null;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Is it bad.?
```

It's not bad, but that method just removes pending posts of Runnable.

Comment: I am aware of that.. And thats exactly what i wanted do.. But was'nt sure about the whole way to do this..

Comment: Could you give me more details?

Answer (score 3):

> Is it bad.?

No(unless you have some problems:)).
Don't forget to cancel that `Runnable` in the `onPause` method so you cancel any pending `Runnable` from running on a possible dead activity.

Comment: @ngesh As nlt mentioned in his answer `removeCallbacks` will not stop the `Runnable` which is currently being executed(if any) it will just stop further `Runnables` from being executed. I don't know if this is a deal breaker for what you're doing.

Comment: I actually have if condition before postDelayed .. So that should't be a problem... But thanks..

Answer (score 1):

There are two main uses for a Handler: (1) to schedule messages and
 runnables to be executed as some point in the future; and (2) to enqueue
  an action to be performed on a different thread than your own.